# Why am i getting kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException even if lateinit property is initialized (probably)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget, kotlin-lateinit

Ok so I declared a lateinit var `job` in a widget as below.

```kotlin
class TempHumidDisplayWidget : AppWidgetProvider(), CoroutineScope {
    private lateinit var job: Job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job
    ...
```

In the onEnabled function, i initialized it:

```kotlin
override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
    job = Job()
    Log.i("com.github.animeshz", "On enabled")
    ...
```

And inside the onUpdate function I am going to use launch which calls the get function of coroutineContext for dispatching a coroutine, which uses the job variable.

```kotlin
override fun onUpdate(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetIds: IntArray
) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
        launch { updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId) }
    }
}
```

And inside the logcat, I am getting the following error:

```kotlin
4425-4425/? I/com.github.animeshz: On enabled
...
2020-05-01 11:06:06.639 4425-4425/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.github.animeshz.shivamwidget, PID: 4425
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.github.animeshz.shivamwidget.TempHumidDisplayWidget: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property job has not been initialized
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1636)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6334)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property job has not been initialized
        at com.github.animeshz.shivamwidget.TempHumidDisplayWidget.getCoroutineContext(TempHumidDisplayWidget.kt:26)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineContextKt.newCoroutineContext(CoroutineContext.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:50)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source)
        at com.github.animeshz.shivamwidget.TempHumidDisplayWidget.onUpdate(TempHumidDisplayWidget.kt:38)
        at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:66)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3171)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1636) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6334) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

> It is clear that `onEnabled` is called before the `onUpdate` method but the `job` variable is not initialized somehow, I don't know how to fix or debug it further

How is this possible that the job variable initialized in the onEnabled is actually not initialized in the onUpdate function? Is this a bug or something?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks all right. Maybe `onEnabled` and `onUpdate` are called on different instances? Try including `hashCode` (or `System.identityHashCode(this)`) in the logs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Plus, if `job` doesn't depend on the `context` parameter, why does it need to be `lateinit` at all?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yes you were right there were different instances of widget class. But if that's the case then how would i create the object when user uses widget and destroy when user removes widget.

Comment: It needs to be lateinit, since i want to attach a job as a lifecycle so that on going tasks can be cancelled if user removes the widget. So a job is created on `onEnabled` and destroyed on `onDisabled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just spitballing, since I don't know details of widgets in Android, but something like this could work:

```
class TempHumidDisplayWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    companion object {
        val jobs = mutableMapOf<Context, Job>()

        fun getScope(context: Context): CoroutineScope {
            val job = jobs[context] ?: throw IllegalStateException("Context $context not enabled currently")
            return object : CoroutineScope { 
                override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        jobs[context] = Job()
        ...
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        jobs.remove(context)?.cancel()
        ...
    }

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        val scope = getScope(context)
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            scope.launch { updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId) }
        }
    }
}
```

It's generally a bad idea to keep references to `Context`s "statically", but this could be all right because they are removed in `onDisabled`. Or maybe use [`WeakHashMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/WeakHashMap) instead.